# Black Screen when pressing a button on a bottom sheet

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, mobile

This is a simple contacts application that is used to create edit and delete data. It is also used to search contacts from this application. The issue that I'm facing is that whenever I create or delete a particular contact from using the bottom sheet when the action is pressed the screen is going black, but the function is being saved.

PS : I have fixed the keyboard issue that I have addressed on the below video, but the black screen issue is still there.

sharing a video link of the issue : https://www.loom.com/share/70219b18490a4e7c986d8f63af584166?sid=e7ade9b5-7efe-47a7-9623-2081d5a8dd90

Link of the Git Repository - GIT - https://github.com/zainahamed/esoft_mad

The issue that I'm facing is that whenever I create or delete a particular contact from using the bottom sheet when the action is pressed the screen is going black, but the function is being saved.

I'm expecting that whenever the bottom sheet action is pressed it should go back to the home screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix black screen issue.**

This happens because you pop() twice from the nivation stack, to solve this problem just remove `Navigator.pop(context);`

Check the code below:

-> Delete a new contact item.

Just remove `Navigator.pop(context);` in delete button widget.

```
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onDelete,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: Text('Delete'),
      ),
```

-> Add a new contact item.

Just remove `Navigator.pop();` from Add/Update button widget

```
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        final contact = Contact(
          id: widget.initialContact?.id,
          name: _nameController.text,
          phone: _phoneController.text,
          email: _emailController.text,
        );
        widget.onSubmit(contact);
      },
      child: Text(widget.initialContact != null ? 'Update' : 'Add'),
    ),
```

**Fix moving bottomSheet along with keyboard**

Set `isScrollControlled` to true.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return ContactForm(
          onSubmit: (contact) async {

            ....
            
          },
        );
      },
    )
```

Wrap your widget `ContactForm` with Padding Width and set padding value to `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets`

```
Padding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _nameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _phoneController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone'),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final contact = Contact(
                  id: widget.initialContact?.id,
                  name: _nameController.text,
                  phone: _phoneController.text,
                  email: _emailController.text,
                );
                widget.onSubmit(contact);
              },
              child: Text(widget.initialContact != null ? 'Update' : 'Add'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```